# CSS overlay vs same looking other color

Tags: css, colors, background-color

Strange I faced this question just now - are there any differences between css background color overlay and same looking color? For ex: designer designed buttons for hover, focus etc. On hover he wrote - **overlay #FFF 15%**. Now sice we use mixins and colors are hex, I have two choices - wrap element with other div or convert my rgba color `rgba(255,255,255,0.15)` to rgba `#FFFFFF26` and use a pseudo class to apply it on hover.

It looks ugly, why not just other background color on hover?

I can get a hex color like this `rgba(255,255,255,0.15)` and it looks the same...

What are the benefits of overlay color (are there any?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have overlay with transparency then the background color will be seen through the overlay. If you apply directly on the button then what is behind it will show (in most cases white) so you have 2 different results

Comment: What I ment to ask is that I can get a hex color from this `rgba(255,255,255,0.15)` and it looks the same

Comment: then the advantage of using overlay is you can always easily add other button with new colors or maybe if you're using themes then focus and hover will obtain the same effect without having to transform.

Comment: if you're using some kind of management system that changes colors of buttons/themes how would you transform? You have to think if you need that

Comment: that's the only advantage, flexibility. If you don't need to use themes or the colors change almost never and you can transform then both are the same.